# Find nearest annotations from user location ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationdistance

I have an array of annotations.I am calculating the distance between each annotation from user location.What I want to know is, how can I find lets say 3 nearest annotations from these distances?

Here is how I am calculating distance from user location to annotations.

```
  CLLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;

  for (Annotation *obj in annotations) {

       CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:obj.coordinate.latitude longitude:obj.coordinate.longitude];
      //  CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        CLLocationDistance dist = [loc distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
        int distance = dist;
        NSLog(@"Distance from Annotations - %i", distance);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userLocation` is static, so don't recreate it each time in your loop. You can also get the location directly with:

```
CLLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;
```

Then, you could do something like, store your distance numbers and annotations into a dictionary, with the distances as keys and the annotations as the values. Once the dictionary is built, sort the `allKeys` array and then you can get the annotations associated with the first 3 keys.

---

Assuming that you always have at least one annotation when you run this:

```
CLLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;
NSMutableDictionary *distances = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (Annotation *obj in annotations) {
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:obj.coordinate.latitude longitude:obj.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [loc distanceFromLocation:userLocation];

    NSLog(@"Distance from Annotations - %f", distance);

    [distances setObject:obj forKey:@( distance )];
}

NSArray *sortedKeys = [[distances allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *closestKeys = [sortedKeys subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(3, sortedKeys.count))];

NSArray *closestAnnotations = [distances objectsForKeys:closestKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: thanks, but could you share some sample code please :-]

Comment: Hi.. the app crashes on keysSortedByValueUsingSelector method.And gives a crash log as ....-[Annotation compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb827f40

Comment: Actually I am using the same statement.......[distances setObject:obj forKey:@(distance)];

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *numbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],
                    nil];

NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedNumbers = [numbers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

you store all distance in an array and sort it and then pick up top there number

```
[sortedNumbers objectAtIndex:0];
[sortedNumbers objectAtIndex:1];
[sortedNumbers objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: How does this allow you to get the annotations associated with those distances?