# Know nearest pin in a MapView from current location

Tags: xcode, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am using a MapView with some pins inside a city added. Also, the current user location is displayed in the map. With these two things known (user location and pins) I would like to show in a label the nearest pin from where the user is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find nearest annotations from user location ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452509/find-nearest-annotations-from-user-location-ios)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find anything related. I don't know anything at all about Objective-C but I am going to check it out.

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct API to find that. You have to loop through all annotations.

```
let pins = mapView.annotations as! [MKAnnotation]
let currentLocation = mapView.userLocation.location!

let nearestPin: MKAnnotation? = pins.reduce((CLLocationDistanceMax, nil)) { (nearest, pin) in
    let coord = pin.coordinate
    let loc = CLLocation(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude)
    let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(loc)
    return distance < nearest.0 ? (distance, pin) : nearest
}.1

// Here, `nearestPin` is `nil` iff there is no annotations on the map.
```

If you don't know the `reduce` method, see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW59).

Answer (score 1):

Use distanceFromLocation to calculate all the distance:

```
let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(toLocation)
```

you could calculate the distances for each pin in a for cycle, so to find the slower one

take a look at this:
[Find nearest annotations from user location ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452509/find-nearest-annotations-from-user-location-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at something like the Mapbox Distance API to do this in a single REST request: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/distance-api/